# C++ CGI file running under Apache fails while using ifstream

Tags: c++, apache, file-io, cgi

I have the following C++ code snippet running as part of a larger CGI program in Apache 2.4 on Windows 8.1:

The following works well:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("filename.txt", ifstream::in);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   //do stuff
}
```

However, I would like to be able to pass the file name rather than a static text string as above.

```
//Define filename as name plus extension
std::string string_filename = parts[1] + "." + parts[3];  //results in filename.extension

ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(string_filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   //do stuff
}
```

This compiles in Visual Studio 2013 with no issue but fails to create an output or any useful debug information when run as CGI application through Apache.

Any specific help would be greatly appreciated.  The pain with CGI is debugging as the program is formatted now to accept POST calls and I have yet to build the appropriate hooks to facilitate offline testing.

Comment: One clarifying comment is that it does not crash.  The program continues to operate.  The file does not open and is not read in but the main() continues on, however the cgi script no longer presents output to the web browser.

Comment: What is `parts`? Have you tried inserting debug output to check whether the filename constructed is correct?

Comment: Parts[1] and [3] are parsing the POST message.  I did create a debug cout to verify the filename is correct.  If I put in a false value my code would comment back that the file could not be found.

Comment: So you also check whether the file exists, meaning that the `open` call actually works? Or how do you check file existence?

Comment: I am running it on my local system.  I can compare the output string to the file in the cgi-bin folder.  When I type the filename in as a string "file.txt" the code works.  When I set filename = "file.txt" and use the variable filename in my open call it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the issue.  It was a bug in my code that Visual Studio 2013 was fixing for me automatically.  When I ran the executable in Apache it no longer provided the crutch and the program exited with a memory error.  I was freeing memory that a pointer was referencing later on in the code.  Visual Studio didn't puke on it, but if I ran without a debugger the app crashed.